# How to get Netbeans PHPUnit code coverage working on Windows?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I am trying to get Netbeans [code coverage checking](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html#code-coverage) feature working. I am working with PHP on a Windows XAMPP setup, and have setup PHPUnit which seems to work fine for running unit tests.

When I right-click my project and select "Code Coverage > Collect and Display Code Coverage", it displays a little bar at the bottom that says "0%" and has options to run tests and get a report.

I run the tests and check the report, yet it remains at 0%. If I check the report it says "No data - have you run your code yet?" I've tried rerunning the tests but it still does this. I've also tried just running the project, and also "debugging" the project to no avail.

Recent information on the topic is hard to come by, but judging by the PHPUnit documentation there [could be an issue with Xdebug](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) (I've enabled it, but no idea if it is working properly as I've not used it from within Netbeans before). Some old sources say that there are two php.ini's in Xampp (one for web, one for CLI), but I can't find a second one (guessing this has since changed).

I'm sure I am probably missing something fairly basic like an Xdebug setting or something... any help?

Here's the XDebug section from my php/php.ini file:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: PhpUnit + Windows = pain in the ass ... I tried to install it, but it had problems with whitespace in the directory names. After 3 days and many unsuccessful attempts I decided to use simpletest instead of that... Was about 5 mins to make that work... Good luck, maybe you should try an unix emulation! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is probably caused by this: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic47374.html. Apparently PHPUnit cannot deal with starting on c:\ and testing something on D:.

Therefore I run any tests I want coverage-reports on from the commandline using the --coverage-html /path/to/directory argument:

```
phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php --configuration phpunit.xml --coverage-html ./report ./unit
```

Where the last argument (./unit) means that this will test als tests in the unit/ subdirectory.

Comment: That works brilliantly, but a shame it can't just be done from Netbeans itself. I've spent the morning fiddling around and even with Xampp and my project files moved onto C:\, it still says 0%. The output window says "Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done", but it seems it doesn't actually read it. I am using the 7.3 beta though (for the HTML5 features) so it may be a bug. Will use your method for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, I've had this problem since version 7.2. Am using 7.2.1 now, but figured it's related to the linked issue... Anyway, testing from the console also allows me to debug the tests themself with Xdebug, and I've not gotten that to work in Netbeans either.

Comment: I had this prob even on the cmd line.  Added this fix and works great now ... https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/commit/ba9e80747f0cac354b57098c5a63dff07b460a27